# Binary addition of Strings

Tags: java, string, binary

I need to combine an array of strings as below ( so as each character in the result string is a bitwise & of the characters in the input string)

```
String a = "10110001"
String b = "01101101"
String c = "10101011"

String result = "00100001"
```

Solution I came up with:

```
long resultLong = 0;

for( String a : inputs )
{
    resultLong = resultLong & Long.parseLong( a ,2);
}

String result = Long.toBinaryString( resultLong );
```

The number of characters in the input string could be very long, and the above solution wouldn't work (NumberFormatException) . I couldn't get my head around how to implement this, what would be the cleanest way ?

Comment: How long is very long?

Comment: @khelwood 3600 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Long is not enough for your use case then you can use `BigInteger`

```
BigInteger(String val, int radix);
```

Which takes a String and radix as the arguments.

```
BigInteger result = new BigInteger(inputs[0], 2);

for (int i = 1; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    result = result.and(new BigInteger(inputs[i], 2));
}

String resultStr = result.toString(2);
```

Comment: This gives me the op 100001 for the input I have given in my question, so missing the leading 0's

Comment: @Chillax `100001` is the correct answer. You can pad it with leading zeroes if you need it to be of your expected length.

Comment: @khelwood Clear

Comment: It's nice to notice that the result can be computed bit per bit (or char per char, if you prefer), so the maximum length of numeric values shouldn't have anything to do with the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here's your algorithm. This will work for any number of `Strings` provided that all the `String`s are of same length:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "10110001";
    String b = "01101101";
    String c = "10101011";

    String arr[] = new String[]{a, b, c};

    String finalString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr[0].length(); i++) {
        int temp = Integer.parseInt("" + arr[0].charAt(i));
        for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            temp = temp & Integer.parseInt("" + arr[j].charAt(i));
        }
        finalString += temp;
    }
    System.out.println(finalString);
}
```

***O/P***

```
00100001
```